# Meaning of the quote: "Adventure. Excitement. A Jedi craves not these things."?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, quotes

Would someone mind explaining this quote?

> “Adventure. Excitement. A Jedi craves not these things”

It seems to be at complete odds with the title "Star Wars: From the Adventures of Luke Skywalker"

As a kid watching the original Star Wars it was the adventures/excitement of Luke Skywalker that made me enjoy the films.

So does a Jedi not crave these things but it's okay to do them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As said on https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi "the Jedi aspired to attain a state of inner tranquility." In other words, part of being a Jedi is trying to divorce yourself from your emotions. This includes the urge for adventure and excitement. However, because Jedi are also devoted to protecting peace and democracy, they may sometimes be compelled to act in a way that might seem adventurous or exciting to an outside observer. The act only violates their code if their motivation was to satisfy an emotional urge.

Comment: Tranquility for the Jedi. Excitement for the audience.